# Why does my display draw behind my screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

So I'm learning pygame and I want to use pixel art for the sprites and I'm trying to scale up my display but it seems it's drawing behind the main display instead of Infront of it

```
import sys, math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
        
fps = 60
is_running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
window_size = [600, 400]
scale_size = [300, 200]
        
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)
display = pygame.Surface(scale_size)
        
player_img = pygame.image.load("images/player.png")
player_pos = [150, 100]
player_move_speed = 3
player_y_momentum = 1
        
while is_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == QUIT:
            is_running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
    surf = pygame.transform.scale(display, window_size)
    screen.blit(surf, (0, 0))
        
    surf.blit(player_img, player_pos)
    surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

I've tried to troubleshoot the problem but I can't seem to find the solution

Comment: You probably want to clear and draw on surf *before* drawing surf to screen

Comment: I feel so dumb , thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The order of drawing/filling is important!

---

Change the order to the following:

```py
while is_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            is_running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    surf = pygame.transform.scale(display, window_size)
    surf.fill((255, 255, 255))

    surf.blit(player_img, player_pos)
    screen.blit(surf, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```